# VNC and the "Use this connection only for resources on its network"

Tags: networking, network-manager, openvpn, vnc

I can't seem to be able to use the TigerVNC viewer or Remmina with OpenVPN when the `use only for resources on this network` flag is checked in `NetworkManager`.

If I uncheck that flag it works as expected, by I end up passing all my internet traffic through a server that is 12.000km away. On the other hand, for other things like `ssh` connections, I can check the flag and I get internet for everything except when sshing into the domain of the VPN server.

If I understand correctly, the flag in NetworkManager sets custom routes for my `domain.com` (as an example) traffic. Then why doesn't VNC go that way by default?

Is there any way to make VNC behave like `ssh` while using VPN? (If the VNC server is in the same domain as the VPN server, use the VPN connection).

Cheers,

Comment: Where is that option? Can't seem to find it in "Edit Connections..."

Comment: It's in the VPN settings, in the IPv4 and IPv6 tabs.

Comment: Ah, I see, and click the Routes button. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use PuTTY and make a tunnel connection to the host.

1.As this [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qW2Uk.jpg), choose the host's IP address.
 2.As this [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tvsyw.jpg), choose the source port and destination. The destination is the thing that you have tried to connect by VPC viewer. The source port can be anything you want.

After that, on the VNC viewer, you should try to connect `127.0.0.1:9000`.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your answer. I was wondering, isn't this the same as creating an `ssh` tunnel? That I know it's a possible solution. However I was wondering if there is some solution using VPN. I'll expand my question accordingly.

Comment: Yes, Exactly, it creates an `ssh tunnel`.  
I don't think so, VNC and `ssh` aren't related.