# Can't connect local network VNC server when OpenVPN client is connected on this server

Tags: networking, openvpn, vnc, tightvncserver

Hardware **A**: Ubuntu 20.04 (192.168.1.61):
Installed VNC server and added OpenVPN client config to some remote server **C**.

Hardware **B**: MacOS 11.1 (192.168.1.51): standart preinstalled VNC client.

From **B** to **A** i have perfect VNC connections when **OpenVPN is disconnected**. But when connect from **A** (as client) to OpenVPN server, VNC connection is immediately down. At the same time `smb`, `ping` (A <-> B) and `traceroute` (A <-> B) works perfect and with same behaviour like with disconnected OpenVPN (down only VNC).

From **B** to **A** (with and without VPN):

```
% traceroute 192.168.1.61
traceroute to 192.168.1.61 (192.168.1.61), 64 hops max, 52 byte packets
 1  192.168.1.61 (192.168.1.61)  27.855 ms  2.296 ms  35.563 ms
```

From **A** to **B** (with and without VPN):

```
$ traceroute 192.168.1.51
traceroute to 192.168.1.51 (192.168.1.51), 64 hops max, 52 byte packets
 1  192.168.1.51 (192.168.1.51)  27.855 ms  2.296 ms  35.563 ms
```

Why VNC isn't work when OpenVPN client connected on VNC server and how to bypass this behaviour? I need connect VNC server to OpenVPN network and don't lost VNC connection in same time.

Comment: Network Manager settings might be a factor: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1179787/vnc-and-the-use-this-connection-only-for-resources-on-its-network

Comment: can you include the output of route

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case i just switch ON this switch across OpenVPN Network in Settings -> Sharing -> Screen Sharing on vnc server OS. You need physical access to vnc server machine and connect OpenVPN first.

[image: Screen Sharing Settings]

Now all works!

Answer (score 1):

### Option #1

Try `ssh`ing from B to A (in a terminal), and then using it as a tunnel to connect VNC.
Steps:

1. `ssh -l <user name> -L 59000:localhost:5900 <server A>`.
   Or  `ssh -L 59000:localhost:5900 <user name>@<server A>`
   Notes: `<user name>` is only needed if not the same in the server and client. 59000 and 5900 can be changed. `<server A>` can be named in `~/.ssh/config` or used directly with ip.
2. VNC to `localhost:5900`.

Sources:

1. https://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-connect-to-vnc-using-ssh/
2. https://health.ucdavis.edu/irc/content/start/computing/vnc_ssh_tunnel.html

### Option #2

[Get the IP](https://whatismyipaddress.com/) of server A in the network and VNC to that IP.

### Related

1. https://superuser.com/questions/744022/cant-vnc-to-a-machine-connected-through-openvpn
2. https://forums.untangle.com/openvpn/12376-vnc-through-openvpn.html